# redirect after logging in rails to desired page

Tags: authentication, devise

below my the app controller and routes, normally when i open localhost:3000 its show me the positions/new page, now i get redirected to the login page which is good, but after logging in it does nothing .... while it should be routed to 'positions#new'

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

routes:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'positions#new'

resources :positions
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are using Devise you need to overwrite `after_sign_in_path` method in your `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`

`def after_sign_in_path 
   "/positions/new"
 end`

Your `SessionController` should look like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    "/positions/new"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes i am using devise, however i can't find a sessions controller, do you know where i can find it, its not between my other controllers..

Comment: Oh, u need to create your own `SessionController`

Comment: i did but doesn't change anything, after log in nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

i added the sessions controller but it doesn't change anything. I also tested it in

```
pry: ➜  positionupdate git:(master) ✗ rails c
[1] pry(main)> User.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 0
```

but i gives me 0 users, while i signed in/up and i have a test user in my seeds, and i runned rails db:drop db:create db migrate db:seed

below my seeds

User.destroy_all

```
puts 'Creating user...'
users_attributes = [
  {
    email:         'barcelona@vt.nl',
    password:      '******',
    barge_name:  'Barcelona',

  },

]
User.create!(users_attributes)
puts 'Finished!
```